# How to add a powerful search functionality to my web app

Tags: angularjs, laravel, search, elasticsearch

I am building an app to browse events. The front end uses angular framework and the backend uses laravel.

How do I add a powerful search functianlity, wherein the user enter his query using an input element and I pass the same to laravel controller.

I now need to return relevant events based on the query.

As of now I am using a very basic algorithm - each word in a query is pushed into an array. Article's are discarded. Based on the length of the array, I try to match each words to some fileds in the table and return unique events.

Is there a better, faster and more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [laravel-search](https://github.com/mmanos/laravel-search)
It has support for a few advanced search methods.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/) for your goals. You can find tutorial here: http://www.fullstackstanley.com/read/simple-search-with-laravel-and-elasticsearch. Also you can use good wrapper https://github.com/mmanos/laravel-search for elastic and another search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Well you added the tag elasticSearch so I guess that's what you are interested in. ElasticSearch has no authentication system so the best way is to create a controller in Laravel that comunicates with elasticSearch a returns the JSON response.

A basic setup will not be hard to do, anything beyond that will need you to learn more advanced concepts of ElasticSearch.

ElasticSearch will handle the search algorithm for you, you just need to pass the value the user is searching and that's it.